# Why Scraping a mobile url link using requests does not return all value?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape this mobile link https://www.tokopedia.com/now/sumo-beras-putih-kemasan-merah-5-kg using a simple requests. That can only be open in app on mobile phone on tokopedia only.

It should return the price and product name however I am not finding it in the content of the request. Do I have to use selenium to wait for it to load? Please do help.

Currently the code is just a simple

```
resp = requests.get("https://www.tokopedia.com/now/sumo-beras-putih-kemasan-merah-5-kg", headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

I tried searching for the price using in however it's not there. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using to look through the request object?

Comment: Page uses JavaScript and ajax to fetch data, to scrape it you need something like puppeteer

Comment: I am just using a simple resp.content to check the content and using ctrl+f to find the price and item name. used a simple "substring" in resp.content to return if true.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to get all the data you are expecting is because this website uses **javascript**. What this means for you is that you need a scraping tool that is capable of rendering javascript.

What you are doing right now is fetching the raw data as your browser would receive it, however you are currently not doing anything with the code written on the website, hence why your data is incomplete.

For starters, I would recommend using Selenium for the job. It'll look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.tokopedia.com/now/sumo-beras-putih-kemasan-merah-5-kg')
print(driver.page_source)
```

To get started with Selenium and its installation, I recommend [this resource](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/python-selenium-to-run-web-automation-test)

Comment: I am getting a You don't have permission to access "http://www.tokopedia.com/now/sumo-beras-putih-kemasan-merah-5-kg" on this server

Comment: If you are using headless, the website might be blocking you. The website could also be blocking you due to your user agent. You may want to take a look at this package: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver, it's an extension of Selenium and doesn't change any syntax, and helps you to not be detected by websites.